# How to add photos to a PDF in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I use this library https://pub.dev/packages/pdf to generate a PDF. The problem is that I can’t manage to add photos to my PDF. The path for each photo is saved in a `List` of objects. This is how I try to approach the implementation:

```
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
​
​
Future<void> generatePDF() async {
​
pdf = pw.Document();
​
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) => [
          pw.Partitions(
            children: [
              pw.Partition(
                child: pw.Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <pw.Widget>[
​
                  /// Photos list
                    pw.ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 1,
                      itemBuilder: (pw.Context context, int index) {
                        return pw.Column(
                          children: _photosList
                                  ?.map(
                                    (photo) async => pw.Column(
                                      children: <pw.Widget>[
                                        pw.Text(
                                            "Photo id: ${photo.photoId} - Photo type: ${photo.photoType}"), // This is displayed correctly for each photo
                                        pw.Image(
                                          pw.MemoryImage(
                                            (await rootBundle
                                                    .load('${photo.photoPath}')) // This is not working because the photos are not in rootBundle and I can't find a solution to replace this line
                                                .buffer
                                                .asUint8List(),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                  ?.toList() ??
                              [],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    print('PDF Generated');
  }
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import dart:io

```
import 'dart:io';
```

If you have a path, you can make a **File** out of it.

```
File photo1 = File(photo.photoPath);
```

Then, you can load in that File to the PDF by using the following statements:

```
MemoryImage memoryImage = pw.MemoryImage(photo1.readAsBytesSync()); //you could use async as well
```

This leaves you with a MemoryImage from you photoPath. Then you can simply add it:

```
pw.Image(memoryImage)
```